# SQL Server : Delete rows based on parameter table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-delete

I would like to create a stored procedure that allows you to delete old rows from tables.
I have a Parameter table that contains the name of the table, the name of the database where the table is located, the schema name, PartDate (Day, Month, Year) and duration.

I want to test on the parameter table if one or more tables exist with different parameters.
I delete the lines that are stored by more than 3 years for example

```
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @SourceDatabase nvarchar(255)
Declare @SourceSchema nvarchar(255)
Declare @SourceTable nvarchar(255)
Declare @DatePart nvarchar(255)
Declare @Duration bit

Set @SourceDatabase = 'DATABASE'
Set @SourceSchema = 'dbo%'
Set @SourceTable = 'TEXT_OLD'
Set @DatePart = 'Day'
Set @Duration = -75

Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    BEGIN TRY 
        --Delete the rows in the table
        SELECT @SQL =N'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CORE.[dbo].[HistoryPeriod] 
        WHERE SourceSchema = @SourceSchema
                  AND SourceTable = @SourceTable 
                  --AND Duration = @Duration
               --   AND DatePart= @DatePart
          )

    BEGIN
            -- DELETE row of table 
            EXEC('
                    DELETE FROM [' + @SourceDatabase + '].[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']
                    WHERE TIMESTAMP < DATEADD([' + @DatePart+ '],[' + @Duration+ '],GETDATE())
            ')
            '
         EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

    END
END
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Looks like you're doing something potentially very dangerous here, from a security perspective.

Comment: remove exec part,you are executing the same in executesql,also post the error

Comment: You could use partitioning to split all tables in different partitions by date and simply delete the old partitions, or move them to cheaper/slower storage. This could also improve performance, because you wouldn't have to rebuild indexes for old rows. Partitioning is available in all SQL Server 2016 editions with SP1

Comment: Thanks for your feedback
In fact, we keep the history of some tables for a certain period. But we want to delete the oldest data from a certain date!

Comment: You have @Duration defined as a bit and then assign is a value of -75. Do you realize that the value of your variable is 1 at that point? Also, you really should avoid column names like "timestamp". Not only is it incredibly ambiguous it is a datatype (which has nothing to do with time of day). Something like DateAdded would add a lot of clarity.